# CAML query to check overlapping DateTime not working

Tags: caml, date-time

I need to check an `SPList` if it contains `Activities` that have overlapping `DateTime` values.

An `Activity` is a type which contains:

- Date on which the activity was done (`ActivityDate`)
- Start time of the activity (`ActivityStartTime`)
- End time of the activity (`ActivityEndTime`)

I have already applied the accepted answer from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods) but I need to do this in CAML so it's a little more efficient.

Here is my method which does the whole thing:

```
    public static bool HandleItemAdded(SPListItem item, SPList list)
    {
        bool conflictExists = false;

        SPListItem currentItem = item;

        //Get data of new item...
        DateTime currentItemDate = DateTime.Parse(currentItem[Variables.activityDateGuid].ToString());
        DateTime tempStart = DateTime.Parse(currentItem[Variables.activityStartTimeGuid].ToString());
        DateTime tempEnd = DateTime.Parse(currentItem[Variables.activityEndTimeGuid].ToString());
        DateTime currentItemStartTime = new DateTime(currentItemDate.Year, currentItemDate.Month, currentItemDate.Day, tempStart.Hour, tempStart.Minute, tempStart.Second);
        DateTime currentItemendTime = new DateTime(currentItemDate.Year, currentItemDate.Month, currentItemDate.Day, tempEnd.Hour, tempEnd.Minute, tempEnd.Second);

        //Get all items who have conflicts...
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery()
        {
            Query = "<Where>" +
                            "<And>" +
                                "<And>" +
                                    "<And>" +
                                        "<Eq>" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name=\"ActivityDate\" />" +
                                            "<Value IncludeTimeValue=\"FALSE\" Type=\"DateTime\">" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(currentItemDate) + "</Value>" +
                                        "</Eq>" +
                                        "<Gt>" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name=\"ActivityEndTime\" />" +
                                            "<Value Type=\"DateTime\">" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(currentItemStartTime) + "</Value>" +
                                        "</Gt>" +
                                    "</And>" +
                                    "<Neq>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" +
                                        "<Value Type=\"Number\">" + currentItem.ID + "</Value>" +
                                    "</Neq>" +                                        
                                "</And>" +
                                "<Lt>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name=\"ActivityStartTime\" />" +
                                    "<Value Type=\"DateTime\">" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(currentItemendTime) + "</Value>" +
                                "</Lt>" +
                            "</And>" +
                        "</Where>" 
        };

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query); //Always empty here...

        // Do something with items...

    }
```

My problem is, I get no returns even if there should be. The ID and Date filters are working as they return the correct values if I take out the other two. But vice versa I also get nothing back.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Weird. When I substitute the `<Gt>` and `<Lt>` with `<Geq>` and `<Leq>`, respectively, it works but I also get conflicts when I create two activities like this:

1. A1: 10.02.2015 09:00 - 10:00
2. A2: 10.02.2015 10:00 - 11:00

This should not cause a conflict.

Comment: I'd try getting the BIWUG CAML Designer and try crafting your query for verification, http://www.biwug.be/resources

Comment: I already did inspecting with SP CAML Query Helper from MS website, but I have not yet found the right constellation of filters.

Comment: Have you check if it can be a timezone problem ? My dates are UTC when I use CAML builders.

Comment: nope. as I said, when I only filter through ActivityDate and ID, it works. only when I also filter through ActivityStartTime and ActivityEndTime I get no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got the solution. Apparently, the default format of a DateTime field when returned through CAML only contains the date part. When I do it like this, I get the expected results:

```
            Query = "<Where>" +
                        "<And>" +
                            "<And>" +
                                "<And>" +
                                    "<Eq>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name=\"ActivityDate\" />" +
                                        "<Value IncludeTimeValue=\"FALSE\" Type=\"DateTime\">" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(currentItemDate) + "</Value>" +
                                    "</Eq>" +
                                    "<Gt>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name=\"ActivityEndTime\"  IncludeTimeValue=\"TRUE\" />" + //Give me also the time...
                                        "<Value Type=\"DateTime\">" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(currentItemStartTime) + "</Value>" +
                                    "</Gt>" +
                                "</And>" +
                                "<Neq>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" +
                                    "<Value Type=\"Number\">" + currentItem.ID + "</Value>" +
                                "</Neq>" +                                        
                            "</And>" +
                            "<Lt>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"ActivityStartTime\"  IncludeTimeValue=\"TRUE\" />" + //Give me also the time...
                                "<Value Type=\"DateTime\">" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(currentItemendTime) + "</Value>" +
                            "</Lt>" +
                        "</And>" +
                    "</Where>"
```

Comment: I think you can skip the first ActivityDate validation, since the StartTime/EndTime also includes the date.